# How to retrieve elements within an element, using accessibility identifiers

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcuitest, xcuielement

I have a VStack, which loops through and prints a view, based on the number of objects within the array. Each view has a unique accessibility identifier `person_x`, dependant on the ID of the person.

```
VStack() {
    ForEach(model.people) { person in
        personView(model: person)
            .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
            .accessibilityIdentifier("person_\(person.id)")
}
```

Within the `personView` there's additional elements which also have accessibility identifiers, but these are not "unique", they're generically named, for example:

```
private var carStack: some View {
    CarSwiftUIView(viewModel: viewModel.carViewModel)
        .accessibilityIdentifier("car")
}
```

So the hierarchy of the accessibility elements would be like this:

1. person_1

   - car
2. person_2

   - car
3. person_3

   - car
4. person_4

   - car
     etc..

How can I interact with a `car` element, within a specific `person` view.

The closest I got, but still without success, was:

```
let elements = app.descendants(matching: .any)["person_1"]
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can create a new query on top of `elements` with the same syntax: `elements.descendants(matching: .any)["car"]`

Comment: Thank you. I can't accept a comment as the answer unfortunately.